# Android - Want app to perform tasks every second

Tags: android, timer, action, handler

I'm trying to get my countdown app to perform its function of updating my current time and date TextView and fire off its MyOnItemSelectedListener every second so that the app counts down dynamically instead of just when onCreate is initiated. If there is a more efficient method then rapidly firing off MyOnItemSelectedListener I would appreciate the criticism.

```
public class TheCount extends Activity {
TextView description=null;
TextView dates=null;
TextView times=null;
TextView output=null;
TextView cDateDisplay=null;
TextView cTimeDisplay=null;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
private int mHour;
private int mMinute;
private int mSecond;
CountdownHelper helper=null;
String countdownId=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.thecount);
    helper=new CountdownHelper(this);
    cTimeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblCurTime);
    cDateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblCurDate);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.countoptions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    description =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblDescriptFed);
    dates =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblDateFed);
    times =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTimeFed);
    output =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);

    countdownId=getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA);
    if (countdownId!=null) {
        load();
    }

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    updateDisplay();

}

private void updateDisplay() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
//@Override
public void run() {
    updatedDisplay();
    }
},0,1000);//Update text every second

}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Normal")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Countdown format is " +
                  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            convertTime();
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("by Days")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Countdown format " +
                      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                convertDays();
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("by Hours")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Countdown format " +
                      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                convertHours();
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("by Minutes")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Countdown format " +
                      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                convertMinutes();
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("by Seconds")){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Countdown format " +
                      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                convertSeconds();
        }

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}

private void convertTime() {
    String dtCountdown = dates.getText().toString() + " " + times.getText().toString();
    String dtCurrent = cDateDisplay.getText().toString() + " " + cTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(dtCountdown);
        Date dateCur = format.parse(dtCurrent);
        long diff = dateCur.getTime() - date.getTime();

        int timeInSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);
        int days, hours, minutes, seconds;
        days = timeInSeconds / 86400;
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (days * 86400);
        hours = timeInSeconds / 3600;
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (hours * 3600);
        minutes = timeInSeconds / 60;
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - (minutes * 60);
        seconds = timeInSeconds;


        System.out.println(date); 
        if(dateCur.compareTo(date)>0){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(days) + " days " + String.valueOf(hours) +
                    " hours \n" + String.valueOf(minutes) + " minutes " + String.valueOf(seconds) + " seconds ago");
        } else {
            output.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(days)) + " days " + String.valueOf(Math.abs(hours)) +
                    " hours \n" + String.valueOf(Math.abs(minutes)) + " minutes " + String.valueOf(Math.abs(seconds)) + " seconds till");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

private void convertDays() {
    String dtCountdown = dates.getText().toString() + " " + times.getText().toString();
    String dtCurrent = cDateDisplay.getText().toString() + " " + cTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(dtCountdown);
        Date dateCur = format.parse(dtCurrent);
        long diff = dateCur.getTime() - date.getTime();

        int timeInSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);
        int days;
        days = timeInSeconds / 86400;

        System.out.println(date); 
        if(dateCur.compareTo(date)>0){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(days) + " days ago");
        } else {
            output.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(days)) + " days till");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

private void convertHours() {
    String dtCountdown = dates.getText().toString() + " " + times.getText().toString();
    String dtCurrent = cDateDisplay.getText().toString() + " " + cTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(dtCountdown);
        Date dateCur = format.parse(dtCurrent);
        long diff = dateCur.getTime() - date.getTime();

        int timeInSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);
        int hours;

        hours = timeInSeconds / 3600;

        System.out.println(date); 
        if(dateCur.compareTo(date)>0){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(hours) + " hours ago");
        } else {
            output.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(hours)) + " hours till");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

private void convertMinutes() {
    String dtCountdown = dates.getText().toString() + " " + times.getText().toString();
    String dtCurrent = cDateDisplay.getText().toString() + " " + cTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(dtCountdown);
        Date dateCur = format.parse(dtCurrent);
        long diff = dateCur.getTime() - date.getTime();

        int timeInSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);
        int minutes;

        minutes = timeInSeconds / 60;

        System.out.println(date); 
        if(dateCur.compareTo(date)>0){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + " minutes ago");
        } else {
            output.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(minutes)) + " minutes till");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

private void convertSeconds() {
    String dtCountdown = dates.getText().toString() + " " + times.getText().toString();
    String dtCurrent = cDateDisplay.getText().toString() + " " + cTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(dtCountdown);
        Date dateCur = format.parse(dtCurrent);
        long diff = dateCur.getTime() - date.getTime();

        int timeInSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);
        int seconds;
        seconds = timeInSeconds;

        System.out.println(date); 
        if(dateCur.compareTo(date)>0){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(seconds) + " seconds ago");
        } else {
            output.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(seconds)) + " seconds till");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

private void updatedDisplay() {
    TextView cDateDisplay=null;
    TextView cTimeDisplay=null;
    cTimeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblCurTime);
    cDateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblCurDate);
    cDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
    cTimeDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(mMinute)).append(":").append(pad(mSecond)));
}

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}  

private void load() {
    Cursor c=helper.getById(countdownId);

    c.moveToFirst();    
    description.setText(helper.getDescription(c));
    dates.setText(helper.getDate(c));
    times.setText(helper.getTime(c) + ":00");

    c.close();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    helper.close();
}
```

}

@NamLe: This crashes the app and brings this up in the LogCat when onCreate() is called.

`02-23 13:19:43.540: I/System.out(11667): Sun Jun 24 00:00:00 MDT 2012
02-23 13:19:44.500: W/dalvikvm(11667): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a351f8)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6773)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3306)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at com.pixelcrunch.crunchtime.TheCount$1.run(TheCount.java:87)
02-23 13:19:44.510: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use `UpdateDisplay` function like below:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            cDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));

            cTimeDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(mMinute)).append(":").append(pad(mSecond))
            );
        }

    },0,1000);//Update text every second
}
```

Finally, you must to call `updateDisplay()` in `onCreate()` function. 
I hope this code would help you finish what you want !

Comment: Thank you! I added the runOnUiThread() code and got it to work. I am not sure how intensive this small task will be and if this is bad coding but for the purpose it seems to work.

Comment: Oh. You should pay attention to background thread and UI thread. In this case, u need UI thread for update date time text. And the Timer object is best choice. If u want to update percent of download thread, u must to use Handler object. Google have many example :D

Answer (score 4):

To run it on the main thread:

```
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    yourMethodOnTheMainThread();
                }
            });
        }
    },0,10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `sendMessageAtTime()` or `postAtTime()` to send yourself a message a second in the future, and handle it then.

[For more information.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also use Timer/TimerTask to fire a operation repeatedly:  https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html