# Is there any intent fired every second in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking for some Intent which get broadcasted every second. I looked into `android.intent.action.TIME_TICK` but this intent get broadcasted every minute. I know AlarmManger/handler/thread can be used for this purpose, but I am inclined to use system broadcasted intent. 
Please share your thoughts?

Comment: is that mean you want to perform some activity on every second ?

Answer (score 6):

I do not think so. First because if system would send a broadcast every second it would drain the battery. Second, if many apps were interested in handling the broadcast, that could seriously slow down the system.

### Update

There is in fact a Intent fired once a minute, but there is restriction on how you can use it

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

Comment: I agree with you. But for my knowledge shake I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible. There is no broadcast intent sent every second.

I've posted a full list of broadcast intents [here](http://pastebin.com/vpg1AJQe) (it's found in the `platforms/android-xx/data/broadcast_actions.txt`, and none of them cover per-second actions. This is further confirmed in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) (searching "second" on the page produces nothing in this context).

You will have to pick one of `AlarmManager`, `Handler`, `Thread`, `Timer`, or something else in this vein. Some of this topic is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406523/android-want-app-to-perform-tasks-every-second), more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822666/how-do-i-make-android-app-which-do-something-every-x-second), some stuff on a timer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188295/how-to-change-a-textview-every-second-in-android), et cetera...