# How to detect change in time each second in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os, android-broadcast, watch-face-api

I am creating a custom watch face for android by following [this tutorial](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-custom-android-wear-watch-face/120). I have implemented broadcast receiver to detect change in time as follows:

Inside my activity I have static block to filter following intents:

```
static {
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
 }
```

My receiver class:

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("myapp", "time changed");
        hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        txt_hrs.setText(String.valueOf(hrs));
        txt_mins.setText(String.valueOf(min));
        txt_sec.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
    }
}
```

And I have  registered receiver inside oncreate():

```
 MyReciever myReciever = new MyReciever();
registerReceiver(myReciever,intentFilter);
```

Above code works fine for hours and minutes, but doesn't work for seconds.

the problem with `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` is that it is broadcasted each minute, not second.

I need to detect change in time each second for the clock on watchface. Anyone have any solution for 'detecting time change per second'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may look [why you are not getting intent after every seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084483/is-there-any-intent-fired-every-second-in-android). So better is to create a separate thread or use asynctask where you need to update your textview on each one seconds.

---

Or you can use [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) for such purpose, like below

```
public void updateTimeOnEachSecond() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Log.d("myapp", "time changed");
            hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txt_hrs.setText(String.valueOf(hrs));
                    txt_mins.setText(String.valueOf(min));
                    txt_sec.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 1000);

}
```

And call this method after initialising each view from activity.

Comment: it works but there is a minor change in your code. You should put setText methods inside  runOnUiThread, otherwise it will throw CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. I have edited the code.please approve that edit.

Comment: @Krupal Hey thanks for that. Yes I missed that. :) Keep it up... do updating