# Android fire event every second having issue

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have following code for Android to display clock at every second. It works correctly for every minute. But how can change it to fire every second?
Appreciated for any help.

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastTime = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Change the time on your widget
        }
    };

IntentFilter mTime = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastTime, mTime);
```

Comment: use timer and fire broadcast every second?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any intent fired every second in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084483/is-there-any-intent-fired-every-second-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no broadcast intent sent every second. You will have to pick one of **AlarmManager**, **Handler**, **Thread**, **Timer**, or something similar.

Some of the similar quesetions are :-

- [Android - Want app to perform tasks every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406523/android-want-app-to-perform-tasks-every-second)
- [How do i make Android app which do something every X second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822666/how-do-i-make-android-app-which-do-something-every-x-second)
- [How to change a TextView every second in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188295/how-to-change-a-textview-every-second-in-android)